# How to convert .mid to .wav file in Android programmatically?

Tags: android, wav, midi

I want to allow user to convert .mid files to .wav files in my Android app.

Actually, there is not plenty of information on the Net about any kind of midi to wav conversion, and so there is very litlle info about doing so in Android.

What should I do? Where to go?

Comment: This question and answer is some sort of spam for a specific library.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "spam for a specific library"? @javdromero

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR

**Dependless on the way featured in this answer you pick, you'll have to include some c code in your project. And also you'll have to include lib lisenced under LGPL-2.1. You should really pay attention to both of these. Read [this](https://github.com/FluidSynth/fluidsynth/wiki/BuildingForAndroid#preface) to understand it better. Really. Do read it. It IS important to understand.**

Lazy option - use [my lib](https://github.com/DanielJorn/fluidsynth-android-lib)

Better option - set FluidSynth up following either of the links ([official github page guide](https://github.com/FluidSynth/fluidsynth/wiki/BuildingForAndroid) and\or [Medium article](https://medium.com/swlh/creating-a-fluidsynth-hello-world-app-for-android-5e112454a8eb)), include [this snippet of code](https://www.fluidsynth.org/api/FileRenderer.html) into your project and you're good to go. This code should be included into your project like it is explained in the Medium article listed above.

Very bad option - use Timidity++.

## More detailed version

### Not recommended option

There are two options when you convert mid files: FluidSynth and Timidity++. I wouldn't recommend you to use Timidity++ for purpose of converting .mid to raw audio. The lib is kind of old and it's not supported; docs and community are imposible to find. FluidSynth is a much better choice: it's newer, it's supported, it's gotta plenty of API docs, its community is kinda lil more alive than Timidity's is. I couldn't get Timidity working on Android.

Anyway, here are some links in case you'd like to use Timidity anyway.

- [somewhat usable timidity lib](https://github.com/sezero/libtimidity)
- [example of converting mid to wav](https://github.com/sezero/libtimidity/blob/master/tests/midi2raw.c)
- [a working app featuring timidity](https://github.com/xperia64/timidity-ae) (I couldn't get anything going on in this code, but this app uses timidity and it's able to convert mid to wav, it's a fact)
- It's not a complete list of timidity resources. Also, there are a few mysterious repos on the web that claim to be either timidity or some kind of timidity lib or even lib for android... But personally I never understood what was going on there, and so I don't recommend to go for timidity.

### Lazy option

The laziest option is to use [my own library](https://github.com/DanielJorn/fluidsynth-android-lib). All the instructions are in the Github readme. Using my lib is not recommended way to do it, probably, since my implementation can have some big performance issues.

You can see examples of using this approach in the lib's readme.

### Better option

The best option to convert .mid to .wav file is to use [FluidSynth](https://github.com/FluidSynth/fluidsynth) software synthesizer. This way you'll have to do some c codding. I told you.

The official github wiki got the [instruction](https://github.com/FluidSynth/fluidsynth/wiki/BuildingForAndroid) on how to set FluidSynth for Android, but I'd suggest you to read [this Medium article](https://medium.com/swlh/creating-a-fluidsynth-hello-world-app-for-android-5e112454a8eb) about configuring this synthesizer instead, 'cause it's a lot more easier to follow and understand.

After you've set this thing up, you can do some neat .mid to .wav conversion. Here is [the official docs](https://www.fluidsynth.org/api/FileRenderer.html) for that. Gonna leave the code here in case the link goes down.

```c
    fluid_settings_t* settings;
    fluid_synth_t* synth;
    fluid_player_t* player;
    fluid_file_renderer_t* renderer;

    settings = new_fluid_settings();

    // specify the file to store the audio to
    // make sure you compiled fluidsynth with libsndfile to get a real wave file
    // otherwise this file will only contain raw s16 stereo PCM
    fluid_settings_setstr(settings, "audio.file.name", "/path/to/output.wav");
    // use number of samples processed as timing source, rather than the system timer
    fluid_settings_setstr(settings, "player.timing-source", "sample");

    // since this is a non-realtime scenario, there is no need to pin the sample data
    fluid_settings_setint(settings, "synth.lock-memory", 0);
    synth = new_fluid_synth(settings);
    // *** loading of a soundfont omitted ***

    player = new_fluid_player(synth);
    fluid_player_add(player, "/path/to/midifile.mid");
    fluid_player_play(player);
    renderer = new_fluid_file_renderer (synth);
    while (fluid_player_get_status(player) == FLUID_PLAYER_PLAYING)
    {
        if (fluid_file_renderer_process_block(renderer) != FLUID_OK)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    // just for sure: stop the playback explicitly and wait until finished
    fluid_player_stop(player);
    fluid_player_join(player);
    delete_fluid_file_renderer(renderer);
    delete_fluid_player(player);
    delete_fluid_synth(synth);
    delete_fluid_settings(settings);
```

... and basically that is it. You can start converting .mid to .wav files right now.

[Here](https://github.com/DanielJorn/Beat-Em-Up/blob/b4f0ff4b137780c8a310f532df365b1bed701364/app/src/main/java/com/danjorn/beatemup/features/track/files/WavFileManager.kt#L13) is the example on how to integrate that code in your project.

[Here](https://github.com/DanielJorn/Beat-Em-Up/blob/c-library/app/src/main/java/com/danjorn/beatemup/features/track/files/WavFileManager.kt#L15) is the example how to use this function in your android code.